# RabbitMQ consumer not consuming when mirrored queue unsynchonized

Tags: rabbitmq, mirroring

My RabbitMQ cluster have two nodes whose queues are mirrored. After a network failure, communication between two nodes are interrupted and two nodes run independently.

During this time, I observed that although all my consumers are connected to queues of both nodes, none of them seems consuming any messages (even after I restart the consumer). I wonder is there any RabbitMQ-specified mechanism causes this?